Auto update golang version that is defined in a go.mod file using Dependabot
Dependabot has been enabled and is creating PRs, but not for the Golang version that is defined in the go.mod file.

Dependabot cannot update the Golang version that is defined in the go.mod file. See this GitHub ticket. As a workaround this GitHub action could be used to remediate the issue.
